# Include Script Field in the "_source" Field - Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am using Open Search using Elasticsearch Query DSL. I have written a query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "_source": ["Field", "matched"],
  "fields": ["matched"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "Field.keyword": {
                    "value": "*little c*",
                    "case_insensitive": true
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "Field.keyword": {
                    "value": "*duffy b*",
                    "case_insensitive": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "matched": {
      "script": {
        "source": "def fields = doc['Field.keyword'].value.splitOnToken(','); def matched = \"\"; def inputs = params.inputs; for (field in fields) { for (String input : inputs) { if (field.trim().toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())) { matched += field.trim() + \", \"; } } } return matched.substring(0, matched.length() - 2)",
        "params": {
          "inputs": ["little c", "duffy b  (Fyb)"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It produces below result

```
    "hits": [
    {
          "_score": 2.0,
          "_source": {
             "Field": "99 N  (N)- ,99 M  (M)- ,Kell  (K)+ ,Cellano  (k)- ,Kidd b  (Jkb)- ,Kidd a  (Jka)+ ,Duffy b  (Fyb)- ,Duffy a  (Fya)+ ,Big E  (E)+ ,Little e  (e)- ,Big C  (C)- ,Little c  (c)+"
             },
             "fields": {
                "matched": [
                   "Duffy b  (Fyb)-, Little c  (c)+"
                 ]
              }
          },
    .....

]
```

I want to include the "matched" field included in "_source" field in the result set. like below.

```
    "hits": [
    {
         "_score": 2.0,
         "_source": {
            "Field": "99 N  (N)- ,99 M  (M)- ,Kell  (K)+ ,Cellano  (k)- ,Kidd b  (Jkb)- ,Kidd a  (Jka)+ ,Duffy b  (Fyb)- ,Duffy a  (Fya)+ ,Big E  (E)+ ,Little e  (e)- ,Big C  (C)- ,Little c  (c)+",
             "matched": [
                "Duffy b  (Fyb)-, Little c  (c)+"
              ]
           },
           "fields": {
              "matched": [
                 "Duffy b  (Fyb)-, Little c  (c)+"
               ]
           }
       },
    .....

]
```

I have tried many ways in the query to do so, but unable to

Comment: You should explore the [highlighting feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html)